# Ignore the response of a web api call

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Our web pages communicate by web api with our database.

Now we have one case where we would like to update some data in the database but we do not need any response of the web api.

In the first try we used HttpClient with

```
HttpResponseMessage response = this.PostAsJsonAsync(apiCall, someData).Result
```

now we are working with RestSharp like

```
restClient.ExecuteAsync(restRequest, IgnoreResponse);
```

But the question remains: what is the proper way to update data with web api when we do not need any response of the web api?

Answer (score 1):

REST services - for update use PUT/PATCH for update and POST as create new. if you dont care about the response - even not for the response code

```
HttpResponseMessage response = this.PostAsJsonAsync(apiCall, someData)
```

just use as you wrote - use HttpClient and dont wait on the result

also when using HttpClient - make sure that you dont create new one for each call